# Is using Home Cloud storage device providing synchronization/ application in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, sync, dropbox, owncloud-server

I am thinking to synchronize my files in a folder in ubuntu, and I am not sure whether to by [WD MY CLOUD HOME](https://www.wdc.com/products/personal-cloud-storage/my-cloud-home.html) or not?! So I would like to ask from experienced and experts that what do you suggest? Does WD My Could have software and application that can be installed in ubuntu and specify a folder to be synched into the storage device (sth similar to DropBox)? 
my
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

> Does WD My Could have software and application that can be installed in ubuntu and specify a folder to be synched into the storage device

Unlikely. Those devices tend to have Windows and/or Apple software. There is an app for Apple to synch with Apple products if you have one of those.

But for Linux you can just use NFS to connect. It is as simple as this:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir wd
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
showmount -e 
sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 {local-ip-adres-to-wd}:/wd /home//wd/
```

(adjust to your preferences) and you have a directory "wd"  inside your home folder where you can copy/paste files to the NAS.

Nothing too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 1TB WD mybooklive in this capacity (as opposed to a cloud device).

Having mounted the WS drive (which incidentally was previously used as a NAS on a windoze file server system) I set up Grsync to ensure that the Dropbox directory in the Home directory on the Ubuntu system disk is updated to provide an maintain an exact copy of the Dropbox directories in the cloud.

I suggest that the same principle could be achieved by using System Settings > Settings > Backups and saving your backups to whatever cloud server you have as a preference (I use Box for a belt and braces approach to this).

You really can't have too many backups...